# How to call the function of C file in .m file for IOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a new `Objective-C project` , it create the file **`ViewController.m`**.

And I add the other source for `C file` and `Header file` in to this `Objective-C project`.

If the function in `C file` is like the following:

```
int dump(addr)
{
   //function code
}
```

I add the `Button` in **`ViewController.m`** like the following code.

```
- (IBAction)showclient:(id)sender {
    //How to call the function in C file here ? 
}
```

How to call the `dump` function in **`ViewController.m`** after I push the `Button`?.

-----------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

The function I want to call in `.m file`
    /*
     * Dump the entire arp table
     */
    int
    dump(addr)
        u_long addr;
    {
        int mib[6];
        size_t needed;
        char *host, *lim, *buf, *next;
        struct rt_msghdr *rtm;
        struct sockaddr_inarp *sin;
        struct sockaddr_dl *sdl;
        extern int h_errno;
        struct hostent *hp;
        int found_entry = 0;

```
    mib[0] = CTL_NET;
    mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
    mib[2] = 0;
    mib[3] = AF_INET;
    mib[4] = NET_RT_FLAGS;
    mib[5] = RTF_LLINFO;
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "route-sysctl-estimate");
    if ((buf = malloc(needed)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
        err(1, "actual retrieval of routing table");
    lim = buf + needed;
    for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen) {
        rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;
        sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);
        sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
        if (addr) {
            if (addr != sin->sin_addr.s_addr)
                continue;
            found_entry = 1;
        }
        if (nflag == 0)
            hp = gethostbyaddr((caddr_t)&(sin->sin_addr),
                sizeof sin->sin_addr, AF_INET);
        else
            hp = 0;
        if (hp)
            host = hp->h_name;
        else {
            host = "?";
            if (h_errno == TRY_AGAIN)
                nflag = 1;
        }
        printf("%s (%s) at ", host, inet_ntoa(sin->sin_addr));
        if (sdl->sdl_alen)
            ether_print((u_char *)LLADDR(sdl));
        else
            printf("(incomplete)");
        if (rtm->rtm_rmx.rmx_expire == 0)
            printf(" permanent");
        if (sin->sin_other & SIN_PROXY)
            printf(" published (proxy only)");
        if (rtm->rtm_addrs & RTA_NETMASK) {
            sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)
                (sdl->sdl_len + (char *)sdl);
            if (sin->sin_addr.s_addr == 0xffffffff)
                printf(" published");
            if (sin->sin_len != 8)
                printf("(weird)");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (found_entry);
}
```

Comment: You can simply use it as in ordinary C. You only need to import header in obj-c class.

Comment: You mean I need to import the header of `C file` , and then I can use the function in `.m file` ?

Comment: your C looks broken to me... syntactically wrong

Comment: exactly the same way as how you call a standard `C` function in `ANSI C`...

Comment: The Kernighan-Ritchie style for parameter declaration confuses people, though it's still valid C syntax. Yet it makes me doubt that dump still does anything useful. Maybe you should get rid of this old crap?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe : That is a example which I reference like the edit. And the content of edit is what the function I want to call

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe thanks - didnt know the old syntax. It didnt compile though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `#import "Cfile.h"` in your `ViewController.m`
2. call it like ordinary C -- `function(parameters);`

(3. friendly advice: buy a book on C)

Comment: The syntax is ancient but legal. Search for Kernighan Ritchie style.

Comment: @Martin, language Objective-C is a thin layer on top of `ANSI C`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe after the edit it works. before it didnt even compile for me

Comment: @Daij-Djan The original `dump` function is proper C and compiles fine in clang. After the edit the parameter type is missing.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I tried it but it seems I tried.. something :D the code was fine indeed - thanks